# Onclick area of map, update the text of a div, or make a div display

Tags: javascript, html, area

I can't get this to work, I tried several methods, and nothing works. I have a

```
<area shape="poly" coords="278,102, 364,146, 364,244, 342,256, 266,218, 266,110, 278,102"   href=""     class="Sursa"/>
```

What I want is, when I click this area, the text of a div in the right of this map, updates. Or, so I can format better, I would prefer to get this to display a specific precoded div. But everything I try doesn't work, nothing updates. As far as I know, area doesn't have an onclick attribute, I tried with Java but I am pretty bad at it. Can anyone help me?

PS: When I click any of these areas, my image is flashing (I think page is reloading), is there any way I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the reloading part  by adding `href="javascript:void(0)"`